# how to solve compact undefined variable error in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-5.8

I want to fetch data from database in table but it show me undefined variable error in view please help me to solve this problem

my controller

```
class showAttendanceController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $users=DB::select('select * from requests');

        return view('showAttendance',compact('users'));
    }
```

my view

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <td>{{$user->date}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->Name}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->Misid}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->semester}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->Department}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->section}}</td>
    <td>{{$user->Attendance}}</td>
```

My Route

```
Route::get('/showrecord','showAttendanceController@index')->name('showrecord');
```

Comment: 1- Are you sure the error originates from the `showAttendance` blade file? 2- I couldnt comment on why compact isnt working but you can alternatively try this: ` return view('showAttendance', [ "users" => $users ] );`

Comment: also did that but same problem

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the error page.

Comment: @user3532758 this is screenshot of the error page  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcGlw.png

Comment: well the error says undefined variable `requests`, it has nothing to do with users...

Comment: I have changed that users variable to requests that is why

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
  $users = DB::table('requests')->get();  
  return view('showAttendance',compact('users'));
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
        <td>{{$user->date}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->Name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->Misid}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->semester}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->Department}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->section}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->Attendance}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: still it gives me undefined variable users error actually the problem is with this $users variable in view file

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it's better to create your table using migrations in order to have Database Consistency.
Further try to use models to interact with Database
for example

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class deposit extends Model
{
    //
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $table = "deposit";
    protected $fillable = [
        'uid', 'amount', 'title', 'description'
    ];

}
```

and then you can use it in your controller

```
     $deposit = deposit::find($request->deposit_id);
            if($deposit){
             return $deposit
            } else { 
             return 'Some Error'}
```

Comment: its not working still give me undefined variable error problem is with that variable when we use in view file

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to use DB in your controller

```
public function index()
{
 $users = DB::table('table_name')->get();  
 return view('showAttendance',compact('users'));
}
```

than you have to confirm your return view file location is right or not.Exmple if your showAttendence file is inside a folder you have to use

```
return view('foldername.showAttendence',compact('users));
```

Comment: still not working is there any other method?

Comment: showing same error ? will you please share screenshot of your code ?

Comment: here is the screenshot of error     https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dfbO.png

Comment: screenshot of your controller and blade file brother